# Make an instance variable maintain its new value

Tags: java, jsp, instance-variables

Hello guys I have JSP and I'm putting some java code and I have a problem with my instance variables Here's my code

```
            String prov, prod, consProv="nothing";
            if(request.getParameter("button1")!= null)
            {
                prov = request.getParameter("cbProv");
                OC_DAO objProvDAO = new OC_DAO();
                datosProv = objProvDAO.mostrarDatos(prov);
                nombresProducto = objProvDAO.listarNomProd(prov);
                consProv = datosProv.getNomProv();
            }
            if(request.getParameter("button2")!= null)
            {
                prod = request.getParameter("cbProd");
                OC_DAO objProdDAO = new OC_DAO();
                datosProd = objProdDAO.mostrarDatProd(prod);
                datosProv = objProdDAO.devolverProveedor(prod);
                nombresProducto = objProdDAO.listarNomProd(datosProv.getNomProv());
            }
            if(request.getParameter("button3") != null && consProv == "nothing")
            {
                System.out.println("WRONG");
            }
            else if(request.getParameter("button3") != null && consProv != "nothing")
            {
                System.out.println("HI");
            }
```

Usually the clicking order should be: Button1, Button2, Button3

The variable is to prevent clicking first button3 instead of button1, by clicking button1 consProv should be filled with it's new value, and it does, the problem is when I click on button3 it seems to the variable "consProv" go back to its default value, is there a way to maintain it's value gained from button1?

Comment: Please post your jsp code also

Answer (score 0):

Your `consProv` always get back to it's default value depends on your code. You set default value for `consProv` once per request-initialized.

You should assign your `consProv` into other scope, such as request or session, which immutable from button3 clicking event.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Can you give an example? I'm new and don't know what scope is :'(

Comment: For example:

`String prov, prod;`

`String consProv = request.getParameter("consProv")`

`if(request.getParameter("button1")!= null){`

`...`

`request.setParameter("consProv",datosProv.getNomProv());`


Wish it would help.